# Why doesn't this form violate the type signature for `$`?

Tags: haskell

The type signature for `$` is as follows:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Thus if `plus1 n = n + 1`, then we have that

```
> ($) plus1 1
2
```

But then why is it that

```
> ($ 1) plus1
2
```

as well? The form `($ 1) plus1` seems to violate the type signature for `$`.

Comment: You are thinking of `(1 $) plus1` probably...

Answer (score 15):

If you try

```
(($) 1) plus1
```

you will get the type error you expect.

The special syntax `($ 1)` is called a section, and stands for `\x -> x $ 1`, which differs from the plain application `($) 1`. This syntax can be used with all infix operators (*) e.g. `(+ 1)` or `(* 4)`.

(*) Except `-`, since `(- 10)` is the negative constant `-10`.